# Compare two files with awk - check if values from two columns in file1 are included somewhere in two columns in file2

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to check (each line) if values from file1 (in column $2 && $3) are somewhere included in file2 (in column $1 && $2). If yes, then I would like to print $1, $2, $3 from file1 as well as $3 from file2 (as a 4th column).

File1:

```
@ 139.51 -62.48
@ 137.36 -63.36
@ 135.44 -64.09
```

File2:

```
137.35 -63.36 6.349
137.36 -63.36 6.348
137.37 -63.36 6.346
```

I've got so far:

```
awk 'NR == FNR {a[$1$2];c[FNR] =$3;next} $2$3 in a {print $1, $2, $3, c[FNR]}' $file2 $file1 > $output
```

But somehow, the resulting values in $4 are not equal to the 3rd column of file2. Could someone help me out? Thank you so much! :)

I am new in programming, and use awk and shell so far, so I am always happy about explanations! Thank you!

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: The expected output in this case should be: @ 137.36 -63.36 6.348

Comment: @IsiSa, then I think you got the answer, posted below :) enjoy learning cheers. Please do post your expected outputs too in code tags for people's easiness.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, thanks so much! That really helped me a lot! And thanks for the note - it's my second question here, so not much used to it yet :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't shown your expected output, so based on your statements only writing this code.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2,$3]=$0;next} (($1,$2) in a){print a[$1,$2],$NF}' fiLE1  fiLE2
```

Output will be as follows.

```
@ 137.36 -63.36 6.348
```

Comment: Very good answer ++ (I was going to post same but was waiting for OP's response on expected output)

Comment: @anubhava, thank you anubhava sir for encouraging, it always boost me up :)